# Why PhoneGap Native Bridge too Slow?

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, trigger.io

I have came across [this](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/02/24/why-trigger-io-doesnt-use-phonegap-5x-faster-native-bridge/). In this they have mentioned that **TRIGGER.IO IS 5X FASTER THAN PHONEGAP**. Trigger.io used the following flow chart for their Native bridge. `What is Phonegap native Bridge Work flow? Why it is too slow? Is that true?`

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me that why i got down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article on Trigger.io's performance being `up to 5 times faster only applied to Android`, and is outdated as we `fixed the slow JS to native bridge last November`. The performance improvements are in version 2.2.0 and newer.

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/hybrid_app_performance_issue

> Yes, I have tested the same sample with latest PhoneGap
>   library(cordova-2.7.0.jar) and JavaScript, Working fine and **PhoneGap getting
>   fast response than Trigger.io**